# How to get Google app script deployment details in run time using JS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I am trying to read deployment information (version number and description) of google sheets addon during runtime using java script.

I found this web app related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69143034/getting-the-version-of-google-web-app-deployment). I am not sure whether it is different as my GAS is not web app.
However I also [tried this API here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/list?apix_params=%7B%22scriptId%22%3A%221yGnUrch-HNbpdPIkCSLllvivVpA6x6_CDdsJZiArN75gf6Vz3lqZZma2%22%7D#authorization-scopes) and it looks OK, I got all the script deployments info when supplying only the script ID.

I modified `appsscript.json` to include all script required scopes (until so now it looks like that

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Jerusalem",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
}
```

this is the call to the API

```
function getDeployments(){


  let OAuthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  let id = ScriptApp.getScriptId();
  
  var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/'+ id + '/deployments';
  
  var options = { "muteHttpExceptions": true,
              "headers": {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  OAuthToken
              }
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch (url, options);
  
  console.log( "util.getDeployment" ,response.getResponseCode())
}
```

but this call returns http code 403.
Please advice

Comment: Can you provide the detailed error message?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your guiding question, it is now clear - details in the answer. Another question though, is it possible to know which deployment is **currently running**, not the list of deployments, but the actual deployment for the current session.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

@Tanaike guiding question helped a lot.

Checking the `response.getContentText()` as opposed `response.getContent()` I checked before made the issue clear. The latter returned array of numbers, whereas the  `response.getContentText()` returns readable string.

Problem was the *App script API* was has not been enabled. Enabling this API solved the problem.